# array form length not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I m newbie in javascript, need some advise.

1) I have a submit array type form in PHP

```
    <form name=\"assessment\" method=\"post\">";

        while($k = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
        { 
          $i++;
          $name = $k['name'];
          $id = $k['student_id'];

         print "\t<td align='center'><br>$i<br><br></td>\n";
         print "\t<td align='center' class=\"H1\"> 
         <font size=3><b>$name</b></font> 
         print "\t<td align='center'> 
         <select style=background:yellow name=result[$i]>
             <option value=\"\" selected> </option>
             <option value=\"1\">1</option>
             <option value=\"2\">2</option>
             <option value=\"3\">3</option>
             <option value=\"4\">4</option>
        </td>\n";
        ......
}

<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onClick=\"return validate4()\">
```

2) i called  javascript to validate the form before register into the DB

---

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function validate4()
{       
var Input = document.assessment.getElementsByName("result[]");
for (i=0; i<Input.length; i++)
{
    if (assessment.Input[i].value == "")
    {
    alert('You have not entered all student attendance, pls check again!');      
    return false;
    }

}
.....
}
</script>
```

---

3) seem the array length giving = 0 & not working, any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please explain your doubt little bit clear. So we can suggest our comments

Comment: "I have a submit array type form in PHP" — That really doesn't matter. You have a problem reading the DOM with JavaScript. You should show an [mcve] with a sample of the HTML generated by the PHP rather than the PHP source code.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get Elements by `'name=result[]'` however your form is using `name=result[$i]` you should look for `'name=result[0]' 1 , 2 ...` in your  javascript, you could use a loop instead of a static search

Comment: the result[] array are dynamic and not static based on the data input while($k = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)).                                         
i need to be able to count the total results[$i] created in order to to make the loop in java. any tought?

Comment: Use another selector then, you could get all select tag.

Answer (score 0):

finally i ve found the solution :
1) i removed the $i => result[$i]

```
   <form name=\"assessment\" method=\"post\">";

   while($k = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
    { 
      $i++;
      $name = $k['name'];
      $id = $k['student_id'];

     print "\t<td align='center'><br>$i<br><br></td>\n";
     print "\t<td align='center' class=\"H1\"> 
     <font size=3><b>$name</b></font> 
     print "\t<td align='center'> 
     <select style=background:yellow name=result[$i]>
```

2) in the validation : 
i ve change to this,

function validate4()
{

```
    var k1=document.getElementsByName("result[]");
    var y1=k1.length;
    console.log(y1);
    for(var x=0;x<y1;x++)
    {
     if(k1[x].value==0||k1[x].value=="")
        {
        alert("atudent attendance not completed, pls check again!");
        return false;
        }
    }
```

now its working fine! Thanks